# Create a database record with a new data instance in same view

Tags: python, django

I have two models
i. AppUserModel

```
class AppUserModel(AbstractUser):
email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True,)
company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
user_type = models.ForeignKey(UserType, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.email
```

ii. Company Model

```
class Company(models.Model):
company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
company_slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)
company_address = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
company_email = models.EmailField(blank=True,null=True)
company_email_cc = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)
company_phone = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True,null=True)
company_RC = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True,null=True)
company_registered_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.company_slug = slugify(self.company_name)
    super(Company, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def __str__(self):
    return self.company_name
```

What I want to do
i. Allow user to register with email, password and company name
ii. Create a Company instance with the company name provided
iii. Create a database instance of the user using the company instance created earlier.

this is my view

```
    def post(self, request):
    register_form = RegisterUserForm(request.POST)

    if register_form.is_valid():
        email = register_form.cleaned_data['email']
        user_company = register_form.cleaned_data['company']
        password1 = register_form.cleaned_data['password1']
        password2 = register_form.cleaned_data['password2']

        new_company = Company.objects.create(
            company_name=user_company,
            user_type='Admin')

        new_user = AppUserModel(
            email=email,
            password=password1,
            user_type='Admin',
            company=new_company
        )
        new_user.save()

    context = {

    }
    return render(request, 'account/register.html', context=context)
```

I keep getting the error below.

```
Cannot assign "'ads'": "AppUserModel.company" must be a "Company" instance.
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... you have almost everything.

First we need to save the company and for that you use the method save (same as user, same as all django models).

Second, I recommend using [transaction.atomic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic) to avoid creating companies but not users if an exception happens.

```py
from django.db import transaction

def post(self, request):
    register_form = RegisterUserForm(request.POST)

    if register_form.is_valid():
        email = register_form.cleaned_data['email']
        user_company = register_form.cleaned_data['company']
        password1 = register_form.cleaned_data['password1']
        password2 = register_form.cleaned_data['password2']

        with transaction.atomic():
            new_company = Company.objects.create(
                company_name=user_company,
                user_type='Admin')

            new_user = AppUserModel(
                email=email,
                password=password1,
                user_type='Admin',
                company=new_company
            )
            new_user.save()
            new_company.save()

    context = {

    }
    return render(request, 'account/register.html', context=context)
```

Comment: thanks for your response, I have edited the original question to show the error I am getting anytime I try to run the view. 

Cannot assign "'ads'": "AppUserModel.company" must be a "Company" instance.